# Atom Electron - Close the window with javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using `Electron` (formerly atom-shell) and would like to have a minimalist frame window so that the three OSX window buttons (close, maximize, minimize) are visible from **within** the HTML page.

I set the Electron option `frame` to `false` when defining the [`BrowserWindow`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions) to have a chromeless, frameless window.

And I thought I could handle the close button with something like this:

```
<a btn href="#" id="close" onclick="window.top.close(); return false"></a>
```

With no luck, sadly. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: A script is only allowed to close a window if it opened it itself.

Comment: Then does the Electron event system allows for some window-level event listening so that I can fire my custom "close" event that would be catched at the `main.js` electron window level?

Comment: I don't know anything about Electron. This is a general rule about Javascript.

Comment: "This is a general rule about Javascript" as typically implemented in a browser; in general 'window' can be defined as the script host wants.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You must access the BrowserWindow object created by your main process and call the `minimize`, `maximize`, and `close` methods on that. You can access this using the `remote` module. Here is an example of binding all three buttons:

```
  const remote = require('electron').remote;

  document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
       window.minimize(); 
  });

  document.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
       if (!window.isMaximized()) {
           window.maximize();          
       } else {
           window.unmaximize();
       }
  });

  document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
       window.close();
  });
```

assuming your min, max, close buttons have ids of `min-btn`, `max-btn`, and `close-btn`, respectively.

You can view the full documentation for the BrowserWindow along with other functionality you might need here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.28.0/api/browser-window/.

It might also help you to take a look at a tutorial I wrote about building a chromeless window that looks like Visual Studio here: http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/making-the-electron-shell-as-pretty-as-the-visual-studio-shell. Your question is covered along with some css to properly position the buttons.

Comment: I didn't turn off the dragging effect on the buttons, hence their lack of reaction when I clicked them. Thanks for the excellent tutorial!

Comment: Note that; if your window has 'resizable: false' option, you can't return window to its original size after click max-btn. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11451

Comment: For anyone else struggling to get buttons to work, [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined).

Answer (score 3):

I have declarate my Window:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn')

notifyBtn.addEventListener('click',function(event){

    const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname,'add.html')
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}, frame: false, transparent: true, alwaysOnTop:true, width: 400, height: 200 })
    win.on('close',function(){win = null})
    win.loadURL(modalPath)
    win.show()

})
```

and for close this:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const remote = electron.remote

const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn')

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: Why is `path` declared but never used? It would be a small change, but still more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question with an alternative technology.

What you want to do is trivially easy in [NW.js](https://nwjs.io), compared to Electron (as is always the case).

```html
<a href="#" onclick="nw.Window.get().close()"></a>
```

The min/max/restore stuff is set up automatically, unless you are hiding the window frame. In which case, here is a simple demo repo:

- https://github.com/nwutils/frameless-example