# Electron setSize method and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, electron

I removed frame from electron and added custom buttons for collapsing, closing and maximizing/minimizing.

collapsing and closing works fine, but minimize/maximize makes blinks and returns to fullscreen

`const [bounds, setBounds] = useState({width: 600, height: 600, x: 50, y: 50})` is a default bounds

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (maximized) {
          remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize()
        } else {
          //here is a problem
          remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().setBounds(bounds)
        }
      }, [bounds, bounds.height, bounds.width, maximized])
```

How to resize window correctly? Also I tried `remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().setSize()`

Comment: Your question is not fully clear. Do you want to resize? Or do you want to maximize/unmaximize? You know that there's something like `remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().unmaximize()`, right? And if the window is fullscreen, you should probably un-fullscreen it first. `remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().setFullScreen(false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a  transparent window with put a fullscreenable = false like this

```html
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: customWidth,
      height: CustomHeight,
      x: positionMarginX,
      y: positionMarginY,
      skipTaskbar: process.platform !== 'darwin',
      fullscreenable: false,
      frame: false,
      resizable: false,
      hasShadow: false,
      transparent: true,
      minimizable: false,
      maximizable: false,
      darkTheme: true,
      closable: false,
      titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
      webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
    })
```

And use IPC render in react side like this

```html
 ipcRenderer.send(
          'window-resize',
          300, // height
          300  // width
        )
```

Then use IPC main to handle that event like this

```html
ipcMain.on('window-resize', (e,height, width) => {
windowSize = {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        x: customX,
        y: customY,
      }
      mainWindow.setBounds(windowSize)
})
```

and if you work on custom control then follow this URL
[Frameless window with controls in electron (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876939/frameless-window-with-controls-in-electron-windows)