# Electron title bar "no-drag" and "drag" not working

Tags: javascript, css, electron, css-float, titlebar

I have a `#topleft` red title bar containing multiple "tab" buttons that should fill all the available space *except* a `#topright` blue block.
It is possible to move the main Electron window by click-and-dragging on `#topleft`'s red background, thanks to `-webkit-app-region: drag;`. This works.

[image]

**Problems**:

1. clicks on `#topright` are ignored: `alert()` is not triggered  (same problem for child elements of this block)
2. `#topright span:hover { background-color: black; }` is ignored
3. `#topright { -webkit-app-region: no-drag; }` is ignored: we can still move the window by click-and-dragging on `#topright` whereas it should not

However if we run the same HTML code *in a browser*, all is working correctly.

**How to solve this in Electron?**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
document.getElementById("topleft").innerHTML += "<button>xyz" + i + "</button>";
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }
#topright { float: right; width: 100px; background-color: blue; -webkit-app-region: no-drag; }
#topright:hover { background-color: black; }
#topleft { background-color: red; -webkit-app-region: drag; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="topright" onclick="alert();">Click here!</div>
<div id="topleft"></div>
```

Note:

- I've already seen I've already seen [Frameless window with controls in electron (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876939/frameless-window-with-controls-in-electron-windows) but it doesn't help here.
- Linked [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Electron but you could try moving the floated blue element within the red element.

```js
const max = 50;
let   i   = 0;

for ( ; i < max; i++ ) {
  document.getElementById( 'topleft' ).innerHTML += `<button>xyz${ i }</button>`;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#topleft {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  padding: 10px;
}

#topright {
  float: right;
  margin: -10px -10px 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}

#topright:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="topleft">
  <div id="topright" onclick="alert();">Click here!</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I added some negative margins so that the blue element would butt up against the edges of the red element (vs being inside the red element because of padding).

[Original Answer using absolute positioning and a "cloned" element.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65499285/1) Updated answer due to new information.

Comment: Thanks for the update @hungerstar! Please add your previous solution at the end of the question, or just a link to the previous edit, it might be useful for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a very simple solution: just move the floating `div` *inside* `#topleft`:

```
<div id="topleft">
    <div id="topright" onclick="alert();">Click here!</div>
</div>
```