# Atom Electron Close and Minimize window using the html button and javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I stated using Electron and trying to make minimize and close button.

index.html

```
    <button id="minus" onclick="minimize()">minimize</span></button>
    <button id="close" onclick="close()">close</span></button>
```

index.js

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;

  function minimize(){
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();  
  }

  function close(){
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();  
  }
```

I must be doing some silly mistake or what but minimize button works perfectly while close button not working.

I also tried EventListener method as mentioned here
[Atom Electron - Close the window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171597/atom-electron-close-the-window-with-javascript#)
And it works perfectly, but why my function approach isn't working??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I Solved this problem just by changing function name of close() function to something else, it seems like close is conflicting with some other function or something like that.