# Electron functions are inaccessible from within renderer/preload scripts even with recommended settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I have spent multiple days reading through tickets and documentation trying to find a solution to this issue and no suggestion has worked. It seems a major oversight or I'm a complete dummy.

Simply, what I want to do is access the electron api from within the application, for example I would like a button that one could click to close, resize etc. the window via the BrowserWindow object from within the render/preload scripts.

I am compiling it via electron forge w/ webpack from example repo provided by electron forge (as opposed to separate webpack), I have `nodeIntegration: true`, `contextIsolation: false` and `enableRemoteModule: true`, the `package.json` also has these options set.

This is the starting project I've used:
https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack

From reading other tickets the generally recommended way is to require the `remote` module via various methods, get the window object and close / execute your action. The issue being this always returns `null` when using:

- `const remote = require('@electron/remote')`
- `const remote = require('electron').remote`
- `const { remote } = require('electron')`

I've tried various sources but for example nothing in this ticket works:
[Atom Electron - Close the window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171597/atom-electron-close-the-window-with-javascript)

I also read this article that seems to say the `remote` module was deprecated and is no longer used, however the code in that doesn't work either: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote

I have created a git repo with the code I'm trying to use:
https://github.com/MajorFailz/electron-problem-example

Please help! I can't really continue development on my project using electron if I can't control the application from within the application. I'm perfectly happy to accept if I've been dumb somehow and missed something vital or fundamental, but as I say it feels like these are the first things any electron noobie would need to know but I'm lost =/

Bonus points if you can provide me a demonstrable example of it working I could look at.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: versions from package

````
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "electron": "16.0.4",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  }```
````

Comment: What version of electron are you using?

Comment: "electron": "16.0.4", have updated ticket

Comment: Have you initialised `@electron/remote/main` in the main process? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote#migrating-from-remote

Comment: Ah, no I hadn't. However I'm getting a new error in the app.
```index.js:495 Uncaught Error: @electron/remote is disabled for this WebContents. Call require("@electron/remote/main").enable(webContents) to enable it.
    at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gothi\Documents\workspace\sinbook-client\.webpack\main\index.js:621:61)
    at IpcMainImpl.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:161:10774)
    at Object.emit (node:events:394:28)```

Comment: I'm not sure where to get the 'webContents' var

Comment: I think it comes from [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents/)

Comment: Ah I've gottit, you have to pass the window so `require("@electron/remote/main").enable(mainWindow.webContents)` in the main process. Ah it's finally working! Thanks @evolutionxbox you're an absolute star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @evolutionxbox 's comments I managed to fix this with the following.

`npm run install --save @electron/remote`

Then in main.js add the following line:
`require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()`

Then finally when you're creating your window in the main process add this:
`require("@electron/remote/main").enable(mainWindow.webContents)`

Now I'm getting the BrowserWindow object when I'm asking for it! Woop!